# ECS cluster without Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I have a requirement of **creating an ECS Cluster without using autoscaling**.

This is because of **a Dedicated Host (DH), Tenancy=Host, is not supported with ASGs**.  DH is mainly for cost savings and for some cases because of the savings is worth doing even if we can't use ASGs.

I understand this can be done using **Macros** and **Custom Resources backed up with Lambda** or using **Troposphere** to loop over the instance.

But to start with any example of the same or any other approach would be really appreciated .

Below is my appsec.yaml template file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Provision Platform Container Service

Parameters:
  PlatformCluster:
    Type: String
  PlatformClusterNotifications:
    Type: String
  PlatformClusterLifecycleNotification:
    Type: String
  Product:
    Type: String
  Environment:
    Type: String
  CDRevisionLoc: 
    Type: String
  ClusterIdentifier:
    Type: Number
  ClusterMinSize:
    Type: Number
  ClusterMaxSize:
    Type: Number
  ClusterSubnets: 
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>    
  NodeImageId: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Image::Id
  NodeOSVolumeSize: 
    Type: Number
    MinValue: 8
  NodeInstanceRole:
    Type: String
  NodeInstanceProfile: 
    Type: String
  NodeKeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  NodeInstanceType:
    Type: String
  NodeSecurityGroups:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>
  HanoverSchedule: 
    Type: String 

Mappings:
  InstanceStoreDevices:
    "i3.2xlarge":
      DEVS: "/dev/nvme0n1"
    "i3.4xlarge":
      DEVS: "/dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1"
    "i3.8xlarge":
      DEVS: "/dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1 /dev/nvme3n1"
    "m5d.2xlarge":
      DEVS: "/dev/nvme1n1"
    "m5d.4xlarge":
      DEVS: "/dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1"
    "c5d.2xlarge":
      DEVS: "/dev/nvme1n1"
    "c5d.4xlarge":
      DEVS: "/dev/nvme1n1"
    "c5d.9xlarge":
      DEVS: "/dev/nvme1n1"

Resources:  
  PlatformClusterLaunchConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          all: [install_cfn, update_ecs_agent, faro_self_install]
        install_cfn:
          files:
            /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                [main]
                stack=${AWS::StackId}
                region=${AWS::Region}
                interval=5
              mode: '000400'
              owner: root
              group: root
            /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                runas=root
                triggers=post.update
                path=Resources.PlatformClusterLaunchConfiguration.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource PlatformClusterLaunchConfiguration --configsets all --region ${AWS::Region}
              mode: '000400'
              owner: root
              group: root
          services:
            sysvinit:
              cfn-hup:
                enabled: True
                ensureRunning: True
                files: [/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf, /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf]
        update_ecs_agent:
          commands:
            update_agent:
              command: yum update -y ecs-init
        faro_self_install:
          packages:
            yum:
              ruby: []
              aws-cli: []
              python27: []
              python27-boto3: []
              epel-release: [] 
              unzip: [] 
              ack: []
              wget: []
              jq: []
          commands:
            self_install:
              command: !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash
                yum -y --security update

                mkdir -p /etc/salt
                cd $(mktemp -d)
                REVNAME=$(basename ${CDRevisionLoc})
                aws --region ${AWS::Region} s3 cp ${CDRevisionLoc} $REVNAME.zip
                unzip -o $REVNAME.zip -d $REVNAME
                chmod +x $REVNAME/install.sh
                ./$REVNAME/install.sh
    Properties:
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: !Ref NodeOSVolumeSize
            VolumeType: gp2
            DeleteOnTermination: True
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvdcz
          VirtualName: ephemeral0
      EbsOptimized: True
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref NodeInstanceProfile
      ImageId: !Ref NodeImageId
      InstanceMonitoring: True
      InstanceType: !Ref NodeInstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref NodeKeyName
      SecurityGroups: !Ref NodeSecurityGroups
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: 
          Fn::Sub: 
            - |
              Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="**"
              MIME-Version: 1.0

              --**
              MIME-Version: 1.0
              Content-Type: text/cloud-boothook; charset="us-ascii"

              cloud-init-per once yum_update yum update -y
              cloud-init-per once install_aws_cfn_bootstrap yum -y install aws-cfn-bootstrap

              cloud-init-per instance custom_docker_options cat <<'EOF' > /etc/sysconfig/docker
              DAEMON_MAXFILES=1048576
              DAEMON_PIDFILE_TIMEOUT=10
              OPTIONS="--default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096"
              EOF

              cloud-init-per instance custom_docker_storage_options cat <<'EOF' > /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage-setup
              DEVS="${InstanceStoreDevices}"
              STORAGE_DRIVER="devicemapper"
              VG=docker
              DATA_SIZE=99%FREE
              AUTO_EXTEND_POOL=yes
              LV_ERROR_WHEN_FULL=yes
              EXTRA_DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="--storage-opt dm.fs=ext4 --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_deletion=true --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G"
              EOF

              cloud-init-per instance custom_ecs_options cat <<'EOF' > /etc/ecs/ecs.config
              ECS_CLUSTER=${PlatformCluster}
              ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE=true
              ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE_NETWORK_HOST=true 
              ECS_DISABLE_PRIVILEGED=true 
              ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS=["json-file", "awslogs", "splunk"] 
              ECS_SELINUX_CAPABLE=false 
              ECS_APPARMOR_CAPABLE=false 
              ECS_ENGINE_TASK_CLEANUP_WAIT_DURATION=10m 
              ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT=1m 
              ECS_DISABLE_IMAGE_CLEANUP=false 
              ECS_IMAGE_CLEANUP_INTERVAL=30m 
              ECS_IMAGE_MINIMUM_CLEANUP_AGE=30m 
              ECS_NUM_IMAGES_DELETE_PER_CYCLE=50 
              ECS_UPDATES_ENABLED=false 
              ECS_DISABLE_METRICS=false 
              ECS_ENABLE_CONTAINER_METADATA=true 
              ECS_AWSVPC_ADDITIONAL_LOCAL_ROUTES=["169.254.120.120/32"] 
              EOF

              --**
              MIME-Version: 1.0
              Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

              #!/bin/bash
              set -e

              # set sysctl before doing anything
              echo "net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.d/99-local.conf
              sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

              /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource PlatformClusterLaunchConfiguration --configsets all --region ${AWS::Region}
              /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource PlatformClusterASG --region ${AWS::Region}
            - PlatformCluster: !Ref PlatformCluster
              InstanceStoreDevices: !FindInMap [InstanceStoreDevices, !Ref NodeInstanceType, "DEVS"]


  PlatformClusterASG:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    DependsOn:
      - PlatformClusterLaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      Cooldown: 900
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 600
      HealthCheckType: EC2
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref PlatformClusterLaunchConfiguration
      VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref ClusterSubnets
      MaxSize: !Ref ClusterMaxSize
      MinSize: !Ref ClusterMinSize
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref ClusterMinSize
      MetricsCollection:
        - 
          Granularity: 1Minute
      NotificationConfigurations:
        -
          NotificationTypes:
            - autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR
            - autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR
          TopicARN: !Ref PlatformClusterNotifications
      TerminationPolicies:
        - NewestInstance
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${Product}${Environment}-pcs${ClusterIdentifier}
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
        - Key: Product
          Value: !Ref Product
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Ref Environment
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
        - Key: Service
          Value: !Sub gtn:${Environment}:pcs
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
        - Key: Schedule
          Value: !Ref HanoverSchedule
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT20M
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
        WaitOnResourceSignals: True
        PauseTime: PT20M
      AutoScalingScheduledAction:
        IgnoreUnmodifiedGroupSizeProperties: True

  PlatformClusterTeardownLifecycleHook:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::LifecycleHook"
    DependsOn:
      - PlatformClusterASG
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: !Ref PlatformClusterASG
      DefaultResult: ABANDON
      HeartbeatTimeout: 900
      LifecycleTransition: autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING
      NotificationTargetARN: !Ref PlatformClusterLifecycleNotification
      RoleARN: !Ref NodeInstanceRole

Outputs:
  ECSAutoScalingGroup:
    Value: !Ref PlatformClusterASG
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about DH, but you could pin your instance to ECS Cluster (if you have ecs-agent installed on instance) by putting `ECS_CLUSTER=YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME` in `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` (you can do it in `user data` scripts)

Comment: "DH is mainly for cost savings" There is no scenario where Dedicated Hosting offers cost savings over default "shared" tenancy.

Comment: I am thinking of looping the instance creation using ansible. But even if I do this, how am I going to include this into my appsec.yml without having to save it into an S3 and incurring additional charges? @Yupik

Answer (score 0):

An ASG is just a convenient way to spin up identical instances using the specified launch configurations.

If you grab the launch configurations and use that to spin up instances, you essentially cut out the ASG.

At the end of the day, you want to set your user data to register your container instance to your cluster.

[image: user_data ec2 launch]

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html

With that, you can create a [launch template](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/introducing-launch-templates-for-amazon-ec2-instances/) and use that to spin up more instances using your dedicated host. You can then build a poor man's ASG using Cloudwatch and Lambda.